# Why is my Parse subscription not receiving any events (not even 'open')?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to host my parse server locally, but on my frontend I do not receive any events, not even the 'open' (connection opened) event. I also do not receive any errors that could help me solve the problem.

On my server I am using the following code:

```
var api = new ParseServer(
{
   (... more properties and keys)
   liveQuery:
   {
      classNames: ['Sticky', 'Canvas']
   }
});

var app = express();

var mountPath = something;
app.use(mountPath, api);

var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function(){ console.log('Running on http://localhost:' + port); });

var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

On the frontend I am using the following code:

```
const stickyQuery = new Parse.Query(Sticky);

this.stickySubscription = await stickyQuery.subscribe();
console.log(this.stickySubscription);  // This gets printed, nothing weird

this.stickySubscription.on('open', () => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: opened');  // This is not printed
});

this.stickySubscription.on('create', (sticky) => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: Sticky created, ', sticky);  // This is also not printed
});

this.stickySubscription.on('update', (sticky) => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: Sticky updated, ', sticky);  // This is not printed
});
```

The subscription gets printed, and I don't see anything weird. It seems like connecting with the Parse server is going wrong. Does someone know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

**Update:** I added the following code to the frontend to show the websocket status and whether error events were triggered, but these events are also not triggered:

```
this.stickySubscription.on('close', () => {
   console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: closed');  //  This is not printed
});

Parse.LiveQuery.on('open', () => {
   console.log('socket connection established');  // Gets printed
});

Parse.LiveQuery.on('close', () => {
   console.log('socket connection closed');  // Is not printed
});

Parse.LiveQuery.on('error', (error) => {
   console.log('socket error: ', error);  // Is not printed
});
```

Comment: Could you please try to also add [these](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#websocket-status) events to check if you get some message from there and specially from the error event?

Comment: This is what you meant right? I did not receive any messages, no error event unfortunately..

Comment: What is the version of Parse Server that you are running?

Comment: I'm running version 3.1.3

Comment: What is the CLP for this class? Do you have any trigger in place for it?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is a CLP?

Comment: Oh I think I found it, you mean Class-level permissions? Is it possible that we have not set any? We use roles and ACLs to manage authorization. And what do you mean with triggers for the CLP?

Comment: How is your CLP setup? Is it public read? The triggers are actually for the class. Do you have any beforeFind or afterFind trigger? Have you also tried the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

In your subscription query , write your className inside quotations:

```
const stickyQuery = new Parse.Query('Sticky');
```

Comment: This is not the problem, since I have a class Sticky that extends a Parse.Object. Creating a Parse.Query(Sticky) should therefore be fine.

Comment: I know but for some reasons I had the same issue and tried this solution and it worked.